# check a checkbox when dropdown changes for multiple checkbox/select combos

Tags: javascript, jquery, onchange

I want to be able to check a checkbox when a dropdown changes. There will be multiple checkbox/dropdown combos which are dynamically created from mySQL based on other selections. I've figured out how to do it for 1 combo, but not for multiple. Will I have to created a function for each combo? Is there a way in jQuery?

Here's my working code for 1 combo. What do I need to do to have multiple checkbox/dropdown combos?

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
    <body>
        <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' id='location_FF' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
        <select name='addWhat[FF]' id='addWhat_FF' onChange='myCheckbox(this.value)'>
            <option value=''> -</option>
            <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
            <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
            <option value='Num'>Number</option>
            <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
        </select>
        <script>
            function myCheckbox(val) {
                var x = document.getElementById("location_FF");
                if (val == "") {
                    x.checked = false;
                } else {
                    x.checked = true;
                }
            }
        </script>
    </body>
</html>
```

Answer (score 0):

You could do with [`jquery.closest()`](https://api.jquery.com/closest/) function call

```js
$(document).on('change', '.combo select', function() {
  let parent = $(this).closest('.combo');
  parent.find('input[type=checkbox]').prop('checked', !!$(this).val().trim())

})
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<div class="combo">
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]'  value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
  <select name='addWhat[FF]'>
    <option value=''> -</option>
    <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
    <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
    <option value='Num'>Number</option>
    <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
  </select>
  </div>

    <div class="combo">
      <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
      <select name='addWhat[FF]' >
        <option value=''> -</option>
        <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
        <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
        <option value='Num'>Number</option>
        <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
      </select>
      </div>

        <div class="combo">
          <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
          <select name='addWhat[FF]'>
            <option value=''> -</option>
            <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
            <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
            <option value='Num'>Number</option>
            <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
          </select>
          </div>
```

Answer (score 0):

I think your output structure is not right, you could return your `html` much better, but I give my solution based on your current output:

```
$('.Selects').change(function() {
  $(this).prev('label').children('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true)
});
```

```js
$('.Selects').change(function() {
  $(this).prev('label').children('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' id='location_FF' class="CheckBoxes" value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
<select name='addWhat[FF]' id='addWhat_FF' class="Selects">
  <option value=''> -</option>
  <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
  <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
  <option value='Num'>Number</option>
  <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
</select>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' id='location_FF' class="CheckBoxes" value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
<select name='addWhat[FF]' id='addWhat_FF' class="Selects">
  <option value=''> -</option>
  <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
  <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
  <option value='Num'>Number</option>
  <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
</select>

<label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' id='location_FF' class="CheckBoxes" value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
<select name='addWhat[FF]' id='addWhat_FF' class="Selects">
  <option value=''> -</option>
  <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
  <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
  <option value='Num'>Number</option>
  <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
</select>
```

And note that, do not use duplicate `ID` *!*

```
location_FF
```

Improved version:

```js
$('.Selective select').change(function() {
  $(this).parent().find('input[type="checkbox"]').attr('checked', true)
});
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>

<div class="Selective">
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
  <select name='addWhat[FF]'>
    <option value=''> -</option>
    <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
    <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
    <option value='Num'>Number</option>
    <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="Selective">
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
  <select name='addWhat[FF]'>
    <option value=''> -</option>
    <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
    <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
    <option value='Num'>Number</option>
    <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
  </select>
</div>

<div class="Selective">
  <label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
  <select name='addWhat[FF]'>
    <option value=''> -</option>
    <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
    <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
    <option value='Num'>Number</option>
    <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
  </select>
</div>
```

Answer (score 0):

Here's a vanilla JS solution if you're interested.

**Edit:** I noticed the other solutions unchecked the box if you clicked on its label.  So I added a `preventDefault()` to stop that.

```js
var drops = document.querySelectorAll(".dropdown");

for (var i = 0; i < drops.length; i++) {
  drops[i].addEventListener('change', (e) => {
    var box = e.target.previousElementSibling.firstElementChild;
    if (e.target.options[e.target.selectedIndex].value == '') {
      box.checked = false;
    } else {
      box.checked = true;
    }
  });
}

var labels = document.querySelectorAll("label");
for (var i = 0; i < labels.length; i++) {  
  labels[i].addEventListener('click', (e) => {
    e.preventDefault();
  });
}
```

```html
<label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' class='location' id='location_FF' value='FF' /> &nbsp;Front Flat </label>
<select name='addWhat[FF]' class="dropdown" id='addWhat_FF'>
  <option value=''> -</option>
  <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
  <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
  <option value='Num'>Number</option>
  <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
</select>
<br>
<label><input type='checkbox' name='location[]' class='location' id='location_BR' value='BR' /> &nbsp;Bottom Round </label>
<select name='addWhat[BF]' class="dropdown" id='addWhat_BR'>
  <option value=''> -</option>
  <option value='Logo'>Logo</option>
  <option value='Nam'>Name</option>
  <option value='Num'>Number</option>
  <option value='Mon'>Monogram</option>
</select>
```

Comment: This is exactly what I'm looking for. Thank you so much.

Comment: One question. Does the script go in the head or the body, or does it matter?

Comment: @DancingBay Ideally, you'd put the script right before your closing `</body>` tag. That way the DOM should be loaded before the script executes. If you need to put it in the `<head>` for some reason, then you may want to wrap it in a `DOMContentLoaded` event handler. https://javascript.info/onload-ondomcontentloaded  Also, if this solution works for you, please mark it correct by hitting that check mark for me.